# Wrong count Vuejs $emit

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have parent component and child, passing data from child to parent.
And in parent component i want to output the length of an array. But the counting goes wrong, it starts only after the 2nd click, and not after the 1st `{{ checkedBrands.length }}`

**Parent:**

```
<v-search-bar @action='takeBrands'/>
```

*data:*

```
 checkedBrands: [],
```

*vue:*

```
takeBrands(data) {
  this.checkedBrands = data;
},
```

**Child:**

```
<label class='custom-checkbox'>
 <input type='checkbox' :value='item.title' v-model='checkedBrands'>
 <span @click='action'>{{ item.title }}</span>
</label>

action() {
  this.$emit('action', this.checkedBrands);
},
```

What i need to add/change?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Are you using the same `checkedBrands` array for multiple children? Overwriting the same variable for multiple children might not work as expected. We would need to see the whole app for that to judge. See link above. I recommend the Vue development tools. With them your browser can look directly into the component values to debug it yourself.

Comment: @PeterKrebs as I see (in the events tab), from the first checkbox selection - an array is created, but it is empty.
On the second selection, the selected item is added.

That being said, everything works fine in the child component.

Comment: Okay. Well, working with arrays and objects has been a problem at times in Vue. You can try without an array if that is the source of the problem. Otherwise see first comment - give us a codepen or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. You just had to use the 'updated' hook in the component.